# Triangle Inequality?

Tags: inequality, logic

I'm having trouble proving the following claim:

$\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_+: T(a, b, c) \Rightarrow [|a − b| < c$ and $|b − c| < a$ and $|a − c| < b]$

Where $T(a, b, c)$ is a predicate for a triangle with sides $a, b, c$.

Don't even know where to start. Can someonle please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly. It is sufficient to prove only $|a-b|<c$.

If $a\geq b$, then $|a-b| = a-b<c$.

Else $|a-b|=b-a<c$

Proved.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I assume that you do not allow a triangle to have zero area.*

From the symmetry of the statement, it suffices to show that $T(a, b, c)$ implies $|a - b| < c$. Start from the triangle inequality:

\begin{align}
a & < b + c & & ; \text{ from } T(a, b, c) \\
a - b & < c.
\end{align}

Or we can start with another triangle inequality
\begin{align}
b & < a + c & & ; \text{ from } T(a, b, c) \\
b - a & < c
\end{align}
These two inequalities imply $|a - b| < c$.